# how to add animation or transition in angular (slider)?

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

I am trying to make slider in angular .I am able to show next and previous image

but I have to do some animation while showing next image (transition).can we do in angular .

here is my code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y5uggz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
 name = 'Angular 6';
  counter = 0;
  slideItems = [
    { src: 'https://placeimg.com/600/600/any', title: 'Title 1' },
    { src: 'https://placeimg.com/600/600/nature', title: 'Title 2' },
    { src: 'https://placeimg.com/600/600/sepia', title: 'Title 3' },
    { src: 'https://placeimg.com/600/600/people', title: 'Title 4' },
    { src: 'https://placeimg.com/600/600/tech', title: 'Title 5' }
  ];

  showNextImage() {
    if (this.counter < this.slideItems.length-1) {
      this.counter = this.counter + 1;
    }
  }

  showPreviousImage() {
    if (this.counter > 0) {
      this.counter = this.counter - 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could use the css propery transition with keyFrame, or you can use jQuery aswell. There are tons of example outta the web that show you how to do it

Comment: JQuery is a very bad advice @JacopoSciampi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First flow the official docs about how to setup animation module [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slider-animation)

```
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [trigger("fade", [  // fade animation
  state("void", style({ opacity: 0 })),
  transition("void <=> *", [animate("0.5s ease-in-out")])
  ])]
}).
```

her how you can change the currenct image base on there index in ther array

```
 showNextImage() {
   if (this.counter < this.slideItems.length -1) {
      this.counter += 1;
    }
  }

 showPreviousImage() {
  if (this.counter >= 1) {
          this.counter = this.counter - 1;
     }
  }
```

the image slider in you html template

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of slideItems;let i = index">
    <img  *ngIf="i == counter" @fade [src]="slideItems[i].src" alt="item.title">
  </li>
</ul>
```

[stackblitz preview](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slider-animation)

Comment: can we add `slideleft` animation